# CSS: text align error

Tags: html, css

I am getting `text-align` error, as i want text align from Left but it starts from center. i have tried to fix but unable to do that. please take a look & correct me.

***css***

```
.text {
   width: 100%;
   height: 10%;
   text-align: left;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

***html***

```
<div class="text"> ....sentence starts form center..... </div>
```

Comment: I am very sure that text is left-aligned.

Comment: What's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/GwbfW/

Comment: but i'm unable. it only aligns when i write e.g `<div ...> <h3> some texts.. </h3> </div>`

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom: the problem in browser, text starts from center only while it should start from left.

Comment: Get FireBug or check it with other developer tools. If I'm correct you should see that this element gets `text-align: center` from somewhere that overrides your `left` value.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle to illustrate your problem. And tell us the browser you use. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Lollero: yes, there is a sibling `div` which uses `text-align:center`

Comment: @user575363 you should tell these elements that they are different if they have different values. `.text1` and `.text2` ( or ID's ) where other one has `center` and the other one has `left` Not the only way to do this though..

Comment: @All: resolved now & just added `float: left;`  instead of `text-align' but not sure why it got fixed with `float`

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this doesn't work you probably have some other css-code that is overriding this one. Check if other styles apply with higher priority or if this one is getting overridden.

Prove of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jB7X3/

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions:

1. You styled more than one. 
   Check if you style `div.text` many times. Sometimes you style one element both in external and internal files, and inline-CSS. (Note: inline-CSS is the strongest for styling)
2. Check your HTML syntax. 
   Closed tags, use quotations, doctype and typing correctly are important.
3. Maybe didn't link to the stylesheet. 
   If you are using one (or more) CSS files, you should check your `<link/>` tags that sourced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your upper html syntax.
like close tag of div.
if not close tag of upper div,that div also work below.

Answer (score 0):

try to use "**!important**" declaration:

```
text-align: left !important;
```

this should override any "text-align" previously defined (except for inline style)